# Blender UV Mapping, coherence of textures

Tags: blender, surface, uv-mapping

I created a connected surface (several deformed and bent planes). Long story short, the UV mapping looked like this:

[image: UV Mapping of connected surface]

I did not find any short tutorial on how to yield a connected surface. I am also aware of the mathematics of a curve, and I don't need absolute control on the look of the texture, only the way it is right now, the textures really look very roughly pixelated.

Is it possible to pull a texture over the surface and to have a more connected UV map?

I also think this question is important so others don't have to buy a whole Udemy course as there has to be a simpler way.

Comment: What does your model look like? If you are looking for something easy and fast you could try _UV_ -> _Smart UV project_ and pull angle limit towards 90 degrees.

Comment: It looks like you used smart UV project. Delete the existing UVMap and use `UV->Follow Active Quads`.

Comment: Hi there, thank you for response. I tried both of your ideas, but it does not change the mapping. Also I tried to reset, unwrap or mark seam etc, but the mapping stays the same. Any idea?